# How to config TestNG test-output folder to be inside Maven target folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

Folks!

I'm new on TestNG, and I'm trying it with Maven (Surefire plugin) and Eclipse.

When my tests are run by Maven its reports are put on target/surefire-reports as expected, but the same tests when run by Eclipse TestNG plugin I'd like them to be put inside a target subfolder also (and as so be cleaned by clean Maven goal and ignored by git, not saying about respecting Maven folder organization), but always go to the default ${basedir}/test-output.

There is a way I can do it?  I'd prefer one that I do not need to manually config Eclipse settings (Couldn't TestNG in detect it's a Maven project and so change its output folder consistently?), but if there is no such way, anyone surely will help.

TIA and regards,

Heleno

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to add the folder created by Eclipse to .gitignore?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos, I suppose so, but I'm wandering if TestNG Eclipse plugin couldn't ajust itself since it is in a Maven project.  It just do something like that when it guesses source folder accordingly in its "New TestNG Class" wizard.

Comment: Besides .gitignore solves git part of the problem.  Cleaning is still an issue that requires another solution (that, I guess, could be solved improving Maven configuration).  If there is a way to solve it not only going around the problem, I would prefer.

Comment: You will need to reconfigure XML Reporter: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports

Comment: @MonisMajeed, it seems cool!!  Why don't you place your comment as an answer?  ;-)

Comment: ok sir.. let me put my comment as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a no way that testng plugin can automatically figure out.

You can set your testng preferences at the workspace or project level.  If you set it at the workbench level then for all projects, by default, testng would put the results there.

Go to Window->Prefs->TestNG.
Change Output directory to be same as maven output directory.

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the way that niharika_neo told...
Elsewise you can also create timestamp enabled folder that would be created for every maven run you do, so won't let your testng reports bother you much. If still bothering put testng reports to a specific folder.

You can provide a different folder in your pom as --

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
```

and under configuration of your maven-surefire-plugin put --

```
<reportsDirectory>./test-output/${timestamp}</reportsDirectory>
```

Comment: I think this is answering the wrong question.  This is adjusting the output folder when the tests are run from Maven, but the OP is asking how to adjust the output folder when the tests are run from Eclipse.

Comment: @RichardNeish please read the first line of my answer...I didnt denied neharika's answer, am just providing a more better way for future running. And you can also see the timestamp i just provided solution for anyone who wants to do a much more configuration so that they dont need to configure projects on each and every eclipse instance they run.

Comment: The solution you suggest only applies if the tests are run from Maven.  The Eclipse TestNG plugin does not follow the folder specified in the Maven pom <reportsDirectory> element, so your answer does not solve the problem of the test output going into the /test-output folder when the tests are run from Eclipse.

Comment: @RichardNeish I never said that this solution is for eclipse run...please see my answer and comment again...i just provided a way for maintaining reports in more better way if user needs to run through maven in future...

Comment: Hi, I have no problem with your solution, it looks useful.  BUT, look at the question: "when run by Eclipse TestNG plugin I'd like them to be put inside a target subfolder also".  The question is asking for how to set the output folder when the test is run from within Eclipse, so your answer does not answer the question.  That's all.

Comment: @Richard Neish okay u won...I just tried to help by providing a better solution dat would help not only OP but others also...u r good to go for a down vote if not done already... Cheers... :)

Comment: regardless of whether you answered this question, i'm glad you posted because i couldnt find this information anywhere else

Comment: @MrTristan ..thanks...at last someone saw the correct purpose of my post which was not an answer but a solution which could help at later stage... :) ...cheers...

Comment: Thanks for helping me about **outputDirectory** for reports with `<reportsDirectory>`

Comment: This works for me since I run with Maven and relevant enough to be posted as an answer. @RichardNeish can shush it. Upvoted. I put it in `./target/test-output/${timestamp}` instead so it gets deleted with `mvn clean`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reconfigure XML Reporter as described at http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports to set the `outputDirectory` property.

From that page:

> In order to configure this reporter you can use the -reporter option
>   in the command line or the Ant task with the nested 
>   element. For each of these you must specify the class
>   org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter. Please note that you cannot
>   configure the built-in reporter because this one will only use default
>   settings. If you need just the XML report with custom settings you
>   will have to add it manually with one of the two methods and disable
>   the default listeners.

It isn't clear how this translates into a configuration for the Maven Surefire plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by going to Window-> Preferences -> TestNG
From there I check marked Absolute output path and entered the absolute path in the Output directory.  For example C:\TestResults